# tricky WHERE clause constraint; filter by one fields value but not omit other possible values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, dax

I have dimension tables *Person*, *Position*, *Department* and a fact table Job. Job marries a position to a person. A person can have more than one job and in more than one department. Need to provide user ability to filter by department – however, if I simply constraint results *WHERE dept_id IN (‘MATH’)*, then I’m not representing an accurate picture; forfeiting an employee’s possible other jobs in other departments. I need to the ability to filter by one department and still surface records of all positions in all departments. Wondering if I should create a bridge table. I will be reporting from the Data Warehouse and SSAS Tabular model so im trying to work the DAX as well as the SQL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to select all of the people who are in that department, without limiting the actual departments returned:

```
...
WHERE person_id IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM Person p
        JOIN Department d
            ON p.department_id = d.department_id
    WHERE d.dept_id = 'MATH'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Russell, I was actually brainstorming this method but still felt that I would be forfeiting results - I understand better after testing it.

Comment: Since there is no FK to dept on the Person table, I needed to bridge via the Fact table. Wondering if there is any reason not to do this. WHERE e.emp_d_sk IN (SELECT DISTINCT j.emp_d_sk 
                          FROM   hcm_dw.dbo.fact_job j 
                                 left join hcm_dw.dbo.dim_employee e 
                                        ON j.emp_d_sk = e.emp_d_sk 
                                 left join hcm_dw.dbo.dim_department d 
                                        ON j.dept_d_sk = d.dept_d_sk 
                          WHERE  d.dept_id IN ('PHYS'))

Comment: Nope, that looks fine to me! It's just adding another table to your join.